# Django Framework : How to catch all occuring server errors centrally and trigger events on such errors

Tags: python, django, events, error-handling, event-handling

I am looking for the best possible solution where I can do the following :

1. Catch every exception where ever it happens in the django applications
2. Trigger various events like mailers , post to Analytics providers or log to the logger.
3. Create a central error handler , that will take different actions on different conditions.

If there is a way to do this , how can it be done and how to go about it?

Comment: As it stands at the moment your question is too broad. It would be better if you show us what you've tried and as you run into difficulties, we can help you to solve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing an app, you can use the following approach:

Whenever your app raises an Exception, use custom, app-specific exceptions like this

```
class FooException(Exception):
    """Base class for all app specific exceptions"""
    pass

classFooPermissionException(FooException):
    """Specific class for permission related exceptions"""
    pass
```

Now your app can provide a custom middleware

```
class FooExceptionMiddleware(object):
    """App specific middleware to handle app specific errors"""

    def process_exception(self, request, e):
        """Processes exceptions"""
        if isinstance(e, FooException):

            if isinstance(e, FooPermissionException):
                # handle PermissionExceptions here...

        return None
```

You can read more about Django middleware [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/).

Edit:

I think you can use the above approach, to catch all `Exceptions`: Have a look at [Django's exception source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/core/exceptions/). Django's internal exceptions are siblings of `Exception`. So with something like the following code, you can possibly catch all exceptions, wherever they are raised in your project:

```
class AllExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, e):
        if isinstance(e, Exception):
            # do stuff
        return None
```

Comment: I want to escape this process of manually adding specific exceptions at places in code.
Is there a specific way where any exception thrown at runtime could be caught along with normal errors like the 4** and 5** errors and specific action can be taken.

Comment: @PriyabrataPatnaik I made an edit. Please note, that this is untested code!

Answer (score 2):

Django has a an event logging functionality which uses Python logger to deliver all the tasks you're looking for. 
You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/)

Comment: I had already looked into this. 
As I am very new to python programming .
It will be good to have a step by step solution for getting this done.
This will definitely help others to include it in their applications as well